# Solve an equation with complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have tried to solve the following equation:

$$
(z+1)^4+4(z-1)^4=0 \quad,\quad z=(a+bi)
$$

If I could leave the $z^4$ alone I could solve it using the formula, but I do not know how to operate with it having additions and substractions.

Can someone please help me?
Thank you!

Comment: shift any one term to the R.H.S, take the fourth roots of both sides and make cases of all possibilities

Answer (score 2):

$$(z+1)^4 +4(z-1)^4=0$$
$$\Rightarrow  \Big(\frac{z+1}{z-1} \Big)^4=-4$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{z+1}{z-1}=\alpha$$
Where $\alpha$ respresent all four roots of $x^4 +4=0$
hence 
$$\Rightarrow \frac{z}{1}= \frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Another idea:
$$(z+1)^4 = - 4(z-1)^4$$
iff
$$z+1 = \root2\of2(z-1)\omega$$
with $\omega =$ some 4th root of $-1$ and
$$z = \frac{\sqrt2\omega+1}{\sqrt2\omega-1}$$
for the different values of $\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

What would you do if you had
$$
(z+1)^4-4(z-1)^4=0
$$
instead? You'd observe it is
$$
((z+1)^2-2(z-1)^2)((z+1)^2+2(z-1)^2)=0
$$
Well, with $+$ you can write it as
$$
(z+1)^4-(2i)^2(z-1)^4=0
$$

Comment: I see your point, how can I solve the equation after having (z+1)4−(2i)2(z−1)4=0 . To leave the Z alone for instance.

Comment: @Marcos You do the same decomposition and you just need to solve two quadratics.

Answer (score 0):

Can you factor $(z+1)^4 + 4(z-1)^4$ (or perhaps an equivalent form of this) into the product of two quadratics?  (Hint: Yes)

Comment: I tried factoring into (z+1)^2(z+1)^2+4(z-1)^2(z-1)^2 . However after expanding it using (a+b)^2 = a^2+2ab+b^2 I get a 4th degree equation; 5-12z+30z^2-12z^3+5z^4. I can't see how to use Ruffini or similar to simplify it and later on use Bhaskara.